# I am getting this error: Type '(err: Error) => void' has no properties in common with type 'QueryOptions'.ts(2559) and I don't know what's the cause

Tags: node.js, typescript, error-handling

Here is my "delete user" route:

[image: Here is my "delete user" route:]

```
app.post("/deleteuser", async (req, res) => {
 const { id } = req?.body;
 await User.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err: Error) => {
  if (err) throw err;
 });
 res.send("success");
});
```

Comment: Please, post the real code in addition. You error message covers a part of it.

Comment: I've edited it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]

```
app.post("/deleteuser", async (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req?.body;
  try {
    await User.findByIdAndDelete(_id);
    res.send('success');
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
    message: err.message
    });
  }
});
```